# Line has been split, total line is different from unsplit line using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, intersection, intersect

In ArcGIS Pro, I've done a intersect on a line based on an area boundary.

When I compare the length of the intersected lines, it should equal the length of the original line. However there is a slight difference of total length between the intersected lines Vs the original lines.

Could anyone explain what's happening?

We need the lengths to be the same for auditing purposes. The example below illustrates this, after performing a intersect, there is a 5.24ft difference in total length.

[image]

[image]

Found another example, where the difference is much greater and the line does not intersect with any boundaries (line fully within area).
The act of putting this feature through a intersect GP tool caused the length to decrease drastically.

[image]

Comment: Use Erase to find a bit that is sticking out.

Comment: Hello, I've tried that. There is nothing sticking out at all :(

Comment: It migh mean some of your lines overlap. Extract end points maybe

Comment: thanks, that might be a good clue. How would I go about detecting that?

Comment: Found another example where the difference is greater (1700) and it does not intersect with any boundaries (line is fully contained within area). So the simple act of performing a Intersect causes the line length to change...

Comment: Yes, the Intersect command performs what used to be called a "clean", which uses the specified (or default) parameters to eliminate slivers and collapse duplicate segments. In crowded extents with multiple conflated segments, "loose" tolerances may shift segments slightly. This is more an issue of "be careful what you ask for" than an error, or even a question.

Comment: If you have the Advanced license you might run a planarize on a copy of your original lines and see if the lengths change.  If so it is likely you have overlaps.  You could also do the same with the Integrate tool at all license levels.  You can try different tolerances to see how that affects your results.  The run your Intersect with the same tolerance and see if that matches.